# Why MySQL Cursor stopped looping while reporting a success

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I created a procedure as below in MySQL workbench 8.0.12 community, win10. A cursor is declared to loop through more than 16000 member's ID in a table to insert their number of orders created in different dates into another table.

Member's IDs and their dates of registration are selected here for the cursor.    `select distinct BAG,AAA from DICT_ALLE_AAAF where AAA>=Date_Memb_Star`. Once I call it `call PRO_MIDD_MEMB_AAAA_1('2017/01/01','2019/11/10',60)`, it only looped through 5 member's IDs and did not report any error. But if I took the `while` loop out of the procedure and with `select Var_BAG` on, the cursor loop went selecting more than 200 member's IDs until it asked me to cancel it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code? Many thanks.

```
delimiter //
create procedure PRO_MIDD_MEMB_AAAA_1
(in Date_Memb_Star date,
in Date_Sale_End date,
in Int_Inte int)
begin

    declare Int_Floo int default 0;
    declare Int_Ceil int;
    declare Int_MembAll int;
    declare Int_Loop int default 1;
    declare Int_MaxiLoop int;
    declare Int_DaySpen int default 30;

    declare Int_Done int;
    declare Var_BAG varchar(16);
    declare Date_Memb_Regi date;
    declare Cur_Memb cursor for 
    select distinct BAG,AAA from DICT_ALLE_AAAF where AAA>=Date_Memb_Star order by BAG;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Int_Done = 1;

    truncate table MIDD_MEMB_AAAA;

    open Cur_Memb;
    read_loop:loop
        fetch Cur_Memb into Var_BAG,Date_Memb_Regi;
        if Int_Done=1 then
            leave read_loop;
        end if;

        /*select Var_BAG;*/

        set Int_MaxiLoop=ceil(datediff(Date_Sale_End,Date_Memb_Regi)/Int_Inte);

        set Int_Floo=0;

            while Int_Loop<=Int_MaxiLoop do  

            set Int_Ceil=Int_Floo+Int_Inte;

            insert into MIDD_MEMB_AAAA
            select Var_BAG,Int_Floo,Int_Ceil, 
            count(distinct BAK)*(Int_DaySpen/Int_Inte) as Numb_Con_Avg
            from OPER_SALE_AAAB 
            where BAG=Var_BAG
            and timestampdiff(hour,Date_Memb_Regi,AAA)/24>Int_Floo 
            and timestampdiff(hour,Date_Memb_Regi,AAA)/24<=Int_Ceil
            and AAB>0;

            set Int_Floo=Int_Floo+Int_Inte;

            set Int_Loop=Int_Loop+1;
        end while;   

        end loop read_loop;

    close Cur_Memb;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little oversight: you forgot to reset your variable `Int_Loop`, so after the first run, it only enters the loop when `Int_MaxiLoop` has a new maximum value.

Reinitialize it (to 1, I assume) before the loop:

```
    ...
    set Int_Floo=0;
    set Int_Loop=1;
    while Int_Loop<=Int_MaxiLoop do  ...
```